# cannot add magento category. error: List of predetermined products classified by does not exist in List of available products classified by

Tags: magento

i am trying to add a new sub category in my magento store.
but i am getting this error: **List of predetermined products classified by does not exist in List of available products classified by.**

any help appreciated...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZyUm.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You most probably removed an attribute to  be listed by in the configuration but the attribute is still used to sort a category.

Comment: thanku for your input, can u please explain a workaround i can do to resolve this ?

Comment: If you remember the attribute, put it back in the configuration if not, you will need to check configuration for available sorting attribute catalog_eav_attribute table and column used_for_sort_by then check the ones that are defined in catalog_category_text that corresponds to the available_sort_by attribute (ID 53 if my installation is good) for the ones that differ

Comment: it did not work.... one of my other stores is also having the same issue!! no idea what to do

Comment: Can it be linked with a common module ?

Comment: basically what i have figured out is that i dont have the option
"Available product listing sort by" in my display setting tab...
DO you have any idea how i could get that option?

Comment: i have added a screen shot in the orignal question for ur reference